# Adding labels to bar chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to add labels on top of the bars in my graph but it is not working. I want it to be the y-value that shows up but instead its numbering the bars.

This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=42cm,paperheight=29.7cm,left =1cm, top = 1cm, right =1cm, bottom = 1cm ,marginparwidth=0cm, includeheadfoot,headheight=66pt, headsep=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{times}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
legend label/.style={font={\Large},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10pt},
axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{1d5893}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.96\linewidth}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{defaultCycle}{%
ybar,ybar legend,fill=customcolor,draw=black,opacity=1,thin,solid,mark=no,mark options=solid,\\%
}
\begin{axis}
[
    xbar,
    cycle list name=defaultCycle,
    width=0.96\linewidth,
    height=0.15\textheight,
    use units,
    scale only axis,
    symbolic x coords={Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    xtick pos=bottom,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0,1.03)},anchor=south west},
    legend columns=-1,
    xtick align=center,
    ytick align=center,
    xtick distance=0.2,
    ytick distance=,
    x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=0.7cm,anchor=north,rotate=0,align=center},
    y tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=2cm,anchor=east,rotate=0,align=right},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    bar width=45pt,
    ymajorgrids,
    xlabel=\textbf{Teams},
    ylabel=\textbf{Points},
    title=\textbf{Team Points},
    ,
    ]
        \addplot+ table [x={x},y={y},meta index=2,col sep=semicolon] {
        x;  y;  z
        Total;  32; 0
        Curie;  4;  0
        Franklin;   6;  0
        Angela; 2;  0
        Ursula; 1;  0
        Warner; 5;  0
        Newton; 8;  0
        Hyems;  5;  0
        Repton; 1;  0
        };
        %Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and the current output: [image: values ontop of the bar do not match y-coord]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please delete the packages that are not useful in the problem. That is, give a minimal example as explained here: [How to make a “minimum example”](http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: ok, i have done that

Comment: Did AndreC's answer solve your problem or do you need further assistance? If yes, what is the (remaining) problem?

Answer (score 1):

I commented the code to show the change. Just delete the `xbar` line. I have deleted the useless packages for this problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{\familydefault}
\usepackage[paperwidth=42cm,paperheight=29.7cm,left =1cm, top = 1cm, right =1cm, bottom = 1cm ,marginparwidth=0cm, includeheadfoot,headheight=66pt, headsep=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
legend label/.style={font={\Large},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10pt},
axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{1d5893}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.96\linewidth}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{defaultCycle}{%
ybar,%ybar legend,
fill=customcolor,draw=black,opacity=1,thin,solid,mark=no,mark options=solid,\\%
}
\begin{axis}
[
%    xbar, <--- comment this line 
    cycle list name=defaultCycle,
    width=0.96\linewidth,
    height=0.15\textheight,
    use units,
    scale only axis,
    symbolic x coords={Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    xtick pos=bottom,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0,1.03)},anchor=south west},
    legend columns=-1,
    xtick align=center,
    ytick align=center,
    xtick distance=0.2,
    ytick distance=,
    x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=0.7cm,anchor=north,rotate=0,align=center},
    y tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=2cm,anchor=east,rotate=0,align=right},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    bar width=45pt,
    ymajorgrids,
    xlabel=\textbf{Teams},
    ylabel=\textbf{Points},
    title=\textbf{Team Points},
    ,
    ]
        \addplot+ table [x={x},y={y},meta index=2,col sep=semicolon] {
        x;  y;  z
        Total;  32; 0
        Curie;  4;  0
        Franklin;   6;  0
        Angela; 2;  0
        Ursula; 1;  0
        Warner; 5;  0
        Newton; 8;  0
        Hyems;  5;  0
        Repton; 1;  0
        };
        %Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, i have also tried this code with some negative values and it is overlapping with the axis. is there a way i can always have the values at the top of the bar.

Comment: By default, it is the key `nodes near coords` that displays the values of `y` next to it. In the case of vertical bars, above the bars.