# Making all bar labels appear above bar and not use scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

Currently all the labels in my bar chart are not appearing above the bars and I'm not sure why. Also, the labels seem to automatically use scientific notation which I don't know how to change either.

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{\familydefault}
\usepackage[paperwidth=42cm,paperheight=29.7cm,left =1cm, top = 1cm, right =1cm, bottom = 1cm ,marginparwidth=0cm, includeheadfoot,headheight=66pt, headsep=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
legend label/.style={font={\Large},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10pt},
axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{1d5893}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.96\linewidth}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{defaultCycle}{%
ybar,%ybar legend,
fill=customcolor,draw=black,opacity=1,thin,solid,mark=no,mark options=solid,\\%
}
\begin{axis}
[
%    xbar, <--- comment this line 
    cycle list name=defaultCycle,
    width=0.96\linewidth,
    height=0.15\textheight,
    use units,
    scale only axis,
    symbolic x coords={Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},,
    ytick pos=left,
    axis y line*=left,
    xtick pos=bottom,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    legend style={draw=none,at={(0,1.03)},anchor=south west},
    legend columns=-1,
    xtick align=center,
    ytick align=center,
    xtick distance=0.2,
    ytick distance=,
    x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=0.7cm,anchor=north,rotate=0,align=center},
    y tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=2cm,anchor=east,rotate=0,align=right},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    bar width=45pt,
    ymajorgrids,
    xlabel=\textbf{Teams},
    ylabel=\textbf{Points},
    title=\textbf{Team Points},
    ,
    ]
        \addplot+ table [x={x},y={y},meta index=2,col sep=semicolon] {
        x;  y;  z
        Total;  17000000; 0
        Curie;  4000000;  0
        Franklin;   6000000;  0
        Angela; -3000000;  0
        Ursula; 1000000;  0
        Warner; 5000000;  0
        Newton; 8000000;  0
        Hyems;  -5000000;  0
        Repton; 1000000;  0
        };
        %Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and current output:

[image]

i would like the labels to all be above the bars and written without the scientific notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick for the number format: `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/fixed}`

Changing that to `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0}` additionally solves the rounding requests from the comment below.

I marked the line in the working example below

For the labels above the bars I introduced a fake column via `\pgfplotstableset{creat on use ...}`, which required to read the table into a macro beforehand. Actually the `pgfplotstableread` thing may not have been needed. Finally a second plot is overlayd the actual bar plot, which produces the labels. Hence, the `nodes near coords` option was moved from the axis options to the specific plot. Otherwise, also the first plot would have created labels below the graph.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{\familydefault}
\usepackage[paperwidth=42cm,paperheight=29.7cm,left =1cm, top = 1cm, right =1cm, bottom = 1cm ,marginparwidth=0cm, includeheadfoot,headheight=66pt, headsep=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={font=\normalsize}} % size graph font
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, calc}

\tikzstyle{chart}=[
legend label/.style={font={\Large},anchor=west,align=left},
legend box/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum size=10pt},
axis/.style={black,semithick,->},
axis label/.style={anchor=east,font={\tiny}}]

\definecolor{customcolor}{HTML}{1d5893}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.96\linewidth}
        \flushleft
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{defaultCycle}{%
                ybar,%ybar legend,
                fill=customcolor,draw=black,opacity=1,thin,solid,mark=no,mark options=solid,\\%
            }
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision = 0}  % <--- add this line
            
            \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon] {
                x;  y;  z
                Total;  17000000.4; 0
                Curie;  4000000.5;  0
                Franklin;   6000000;  0
                Angela; -3000000;  0
                Ursula; 1000000;  0
                Warner; 5000000;  0
                Newton; 8000000;  0
                Hyems;  -5000000;  0
                Repton; 1000000;  0
            } \data
            
            \pgfplotstableset{
                create on use/labelY/.style={
                    create col/expr={\thisrow{y}>0)*\thisrow{y}}
                }
            }
            
            \begin{axis}
                [
                %    xbar, <--- comment this line 
                cycle list name=defaultCycle,
                width=0.96\linewidth,
                height=0.15\textheight,
                use units,
                scale only axis,
                symbolic x coords={Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton},
                xtick=data,
                yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},,
                ytick pos=left,
                axis y line*=left,
                xtick pos=bottom,
                axis x line*=bottom,
                legend style={draw=none,at={(0,1.03)},anchor=south west},
                legend columns=-1,
                xtick align=center,
                ytick align=center,
                xtick distance=0.2,
                ytick distance=,
                x tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=0.7cm,anchor=north,rotate=0,align=center},
                y tick label style ={font=\normalsize,text width=2cm,anchor=east,rotate=0,align=right},
                scaled y ticks=false,
                bar width=45pt,
                ymajorgrids,
                xlabel=\textbf{Teams},
                ylabel=\textbf{Points},
                title=\textbf{Team Points},
                ,
                ]
                \addplot+ table [x={x},y={y}] {\data};
                \addplot+[
                    nodes near coords,
                    nodes near coords align = above,
                    point meta=explicit
                    ] table [x={x},y={labelY}, meta = {y} ] {\data};
                %Total,Curie,Franklin,Angela,Ursula,Warner,Newton,Hyems,Repton
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: hi, this has fixed the formatting of the numbers but the negative values are still under the bar. do you know how to place them above the bars as well. thank you for answering my question!!

Comment: This all seems to be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598935/adding-labels-to-bar-chart, right?

Comment: yes, it is related

Comment: I tried some solutions using `visualization depends on` but that did not work. What is the reason the labels should appear above the bars for negative values? Is the only issue the overlap with the axis or is it a matter of style preference? And another thing: I assume that all should behave as automatic as possible, right? Prefereably the data should only be entered once and not twice or even more times, right?

Comment: both a style preference and the axis overlapping. i've also noticed that it automatically rounds to dp if i use values that aren't to the nearest whole number. do you know a way to fix that?

Comment: Finally, I found a solution for the label positioning. The Rounding issue could also be solved by adjusting the /pgf/number/format line a bit.

Comment: Hi @texstar, did the solution solve your question? If so, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer. (Maybe also check your other questions here on TeX.SE)

Comment: yes, it works. thank you so much :)